# Load job to BigQuery failing when reading schema from cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a code to load the data from cloud storage to BigQuery. The code is given below. This code is failing with

"**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://abhishek-rajeevan-dfpart123/SCHEMA_FILES/RAW_SCHEMA.json'**".

Can someone help me understand why is this failing? In the same code I am using the URI as file path for pandas to load the data to a dataframe, however it fails when I am using the URI as file path for "bq_client.schema_from_json". What is the proper way to read a schema file stored in GCS.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

bq_client = bigquery.Client()
storage_client = storage.Client()

def load_wwmd_raw(raw_table_id,schema_uri):

    df = pd.read_excel(source_uri,engine = 'openpyxl')
    df['status'] = 'A'
    df['insert_timestamp'] = dt.datetime.now()
    df['update_timestamp'] = ''

    # set the schema for the df read
    schema = bq_client.schema_from_json(schema_uri)

    # set the job configuration
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema = schema,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        )

    # run the load job
    job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, raw_table_id, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

if __name__ == '__main__':

    project_id      = '<ProjectIDHere>'
    dataset_nm      = 'test_dataset'
    raw_table_nm    = 'test_raw'
    raw_table_id = '{project_id}.{dataset_nm}.{raw_table_nm}'.format(project_id = project_id, dataset_nm = dataset_nm, raw_table_nm = raw_table_nm)
    source_uri      = 'gs://<bucketName>/RAW_FILES/test_data.xlsx'
    schema_uri      = 'gs://<BucketName>/SCHEMA_FILES/RAW_SCHEMA.json'

    load_wwmd_raw(raw_table_id,schema_uri)
```

Comment: Are you sure it exists? What’s the output of running `gsutil ls gs://abhishek-rajeevan-dfpart123/SCHEMA_FILES/RAW_SCHEMA.json`   ?

Comment: Hi @jamiet, yes the file exists at the right path. Here's the output of the above command - "gs://abhishek-rajeevan-dfpart123/SCHEMA_FILES/RAW_SCHEMA.json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

**Code:**

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

bq_client = bigquery.Client()
storage_client = storage.Client()

def load_wwmd_raw(raw_table_id,destination_file_name):

    df = pd.read_excel(source_uri,engine = 'openpyxl')
    df['status'] = 'A'
    df['insert_timestamp'] = dt.datetime.now()
    df['update_timestamp'] = ''

    # set the schema for the df read
    schema = bq_client.schema_from_json(destination_file_name)

    # set the job configuration
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema = schema,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        )

    # run the load job
    job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, raw_table_id, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
    print(df)
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
    
    
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
 

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Downloaded storage object {} from bucket {} to local file {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, bucket_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    project_id      = '<projectID>'
    dataset_nm      = '<datasetName>'
    raw_table_nm    = '<tableName>'
    raw_table_id = '{project_id}.{dataset_nm}.{raw_table_nm}'.format(project_id = project_id, dataset_nm = dataset_nm, raw_table_nm = raw_table_nm)
    source_uri      = 'gs://<bucketName>/RAW_FILES/test_data.xlsx'
    
    
    
    
    bucket_name = "<bucketName>"
    source_blob_name = "file/sample.json"
    filename = source_blob_name.split("/")
    destination_file_name = f"/file/folder/{filename[-1]}"
    download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name)
    
    load_wwmd_raw(raw_table_id,destination_file_name)
```

In this code I added a function named `download_blob` that downloads the file to load from
[Google Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#downloading-an-object) since `schema_to_json` method does not allow directory from GCS(Referenced from this [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/main/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L3886))

So as a workaround the code will download first the file to load from GCS bucket. After the download, it will proceed to load the file (Source from the local file path)  to the function `load_wwmd_raw`. Just change the appropriate parameters.

In my replication I was able to load a json file from my local path that was downloaded from the GCS bucket to my bigquery dataset.